# Error when trying to compile a keras model ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for Tensor with dtype float32

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a speech recognizer using tensorflow and am getting this error that

> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int64 for Tensor with
>   dtype float32: 'Tensor("loss_2/lambda_loss/ExpandDims:0", shape=(?,
>   1), dtype=float32)'

and

> TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match
>   type int64 of argument 'x'.

Minimum Running Code where tensorflow is imported as tf

```
train_input_val = tf.keras.layers.Input(name='the_input', shape=[None,num_features], dtype='float32')
seq_len = tf.keras.layers.Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')

y_pred = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(ctc_decode_func ,name = 'lambda')([train_input_val, seq_len])
model2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[train_input_val,seq_len],outputs=y_pred)

model2.compile(loss={'lambda': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_true}, optimizer='adam')
```

and ctc_decode_func is defined as

```
def ctc_decode_func(args):
    y_pred, seq_len = args
    y_pred,log_prob = tf.keras.backend.ctc_decode(y_pred, tf.squeeze(seq_len))
    return y_pred
```

I tried casting everything to int64 , but still the error persisted. I dont Even know which part of lambda layer is throwing the error.

Please Help